# Get attachments from xml data using c# to Crm 2015

Tags: c#, xml, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

we have a website that the customer writes her incident with attachments.
I can get the incident and save it to Crm 2015 system.
Hovewer i want to save also the attachments like pictures etc.

I get the incidents from xml and read one by one and save the to Crm 2015 System:

```
foreach (XElement xmlIncident in xmlIncidents)
{

}
```

In this foreach i can get the attachment values:

```
var attachments = xmlIncident.Elements("attachments"); //get the collection of attachments.
```

As an example, ın may example incident i have 4 jpg photosand one of them seems to be like this in c# code:

https://docs.sikayetvar.com/complaint/1054/10543034/gbhjk-1528636381_160x160.jpg
  https://docs.sikayetvar.com/complaint/1054/10543034/gbhjk-1528636381.jpg
  photo

My question is how can i get the attachments form xml data and save it to Crm 2015 incident table using c#

[image]

Comment: Does the xml file just contain the URL path names to the jpg files and you simply want to extract the file names from the Xml?  Then you want to attch the xml files to CRM 2015 Email?

Comment: Yes the xml file just contain the url path names to the jpg files. I want to save the exact files tı the Crm 2015 İncident entity (table).

Comment: See following webpage for adding images dynamically to CRM : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn511697.aspx

Comment: The question is ambiguous with the title, what is the problem is not clear whether getting the file from the xml is the problem or saving it in crm in the problem ? Try changing the Title that will help

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not a good idea to update the CRM database directly as there are plenty of things available in the CRM SDK.

Steps to perform:

1. Get the file path from the XML
2. verify the file type to be **jpg** then read the file as **Base64**
   string
3. Create Entity of type `Annotation` where `objectid` = record GUID

Look at the below code it should work for you

```
Guid AttachToIncident(string filePath, Guid recordGuid){    
    Func<string,string> imageToBase64 = (fpath) => {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(fpath))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memStrm = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(memStrm, image.RawFormat);
                byte[] imageBytes = memStrm.ToArray();
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }   
    };

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    Guid attachmentId = Guid.Empty;

    Entity newAnnotation = new Entity("annotation");
    newAnnotation["subject"] = "external attachment";
    newAnnotation["filename"] = filename;
    newAnnotation["mimetype"] = @"image/jpeg";
    newAnnotation["documentbody"] = imageToBase64(filePath);
    newAnnotation["objectid"] = new EntityReference("incident", recordGuid);

   //you must be knowing what this service is ;)
    attachmentId = orgService.Create(newAnnotation); 
    return attachmentId;    
}
```

Comment: Hi,Tahnks for your help. Teh attachments can be video format or image. How can i save video files. Also i wanto to attach more than one image to incident. How can i do that?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to save video as an attachment due to file size/type, alternatively you can better upload it to some media services like _youtube_ or _network drive_ and embed it in a `IFrame` and display it in a tab. But this is how you can encode Audio, Video if you really wanted it to http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri/